# Variable global en vue.js modificable y accesible desde cualquier lugar

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Vue.js y necesito una variable global que sea accesible y modificable desde cualquier parte de la aplicación.
En este caso no me importa la seguridad porque es una aplicación que no se comunica con el servidor.
He probado diferentes formas que he encontrado por Internet pero no consigo que me salga.
Esta es una de ellas:

```
Vue.mixin({
  data: function() {
    return {
      get variableGlobal() {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
})

new Vue({

  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Despues en una template tengo esto:

```
<p v-if="variableGlobal"></p>
```

Y en otra tempate distinta hago esto para que se oculte ese `<p>`:

```
<template>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
         methods: {
             metodo1() {
                 this.variableGlobal = false;
             }
         }
     }
</script>
```

Pero no funciona.
Agradecería si alguien me pudiese ayudar.

Comment: No funciona porque el mixin no hace que "esa variable" sea compartida en los componentes en los que utilizas el mixin. Si no que cada componente tendrá esa variable en su instancia, es decir será local en cada componente. Si realmente no puedes establecer una comunicación padre hijo entre los componentes que intervienen (props, model, provide-inject), la única alternativa que te queda es usar vuex y mantener un estado de la aplicación (aunque para una sola variable tampoco tenga mucho sentido). Necesitamos un poco más de contexto para responderte mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar:

```
Vue.prototype.$variableGlobal= true
```

Y con esto ya puedes acceder a ella incluso antes de crearse un componente, por ejemplo:

```
beforeCreate: function() {
    console.log(this.$variableGlobal)
    this.$variableGlobal = false
  }
```

Puedes encontrar mas informacion sobre esto en la documentacion: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html